# How can I change a JPanel's opacity when focused?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make my JPanel change opacity when focused.

Right now, I use this;

```
Main main = new Main();
Main.setOpacity(0.75f);
```

This works fine but is there any way I can make the opacity go down when the JPanel is not focused and then back up to .75 when it regains focus?

Comment: You must be changing opacity on focusGained() event. Then restore the opacity on focusLost() event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by implementing a `FocusListener`.

the method `public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)` sets the opacity to 0.75 and the method `public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)` decreases the value according to your needs.

detailed description could be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html)

Comment: Using a focusListener I can't get the JPanel to change opacity. Directly in the focusListener functions it won't let me use setOpacity and when I use a static float for it it won't change either.

Comment: Ooh nevermind! I managed to fix it by just saying 'setOpacity();' in the focuslistener